# Show that $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^kx^k}{k}$ converges uniformly on [0,1]

Tags: uniform-convergence

The problem is stated as:

> Show that $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^kx^k}{k}$ converges uniformly on [0,1]

**My attempt:**

So, since we have an alternating series, applying Weierstrass M - test in this case, will not help since we will have that $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} u_k(x) = 1/k$ for $u_k(x) := (-1)^k x^k / k$. But $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1/k$, diverges.

Instead, we check uniform convergence applying the definition of uniform convergence directly:

$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|\sum _{k=n}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^kx^k}{k}| \leq \sup_{x\in[0,1]}\sum _{k=n}^{\infty }|\frac{\left(-1\right)^kx^k}{k}| = \sup_{x\in[0,1]}\sum _{k=n}^{\infty }|\frac{x^k}{k}| = \sum _{k=n}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k}$

But this diverges too! In my textbook however, they somehow went from $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|\sum _{k=n}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^kx^k}{k}| \leq 1/n \rightarrow 0, n\rightarrow \infty$. However, I can't see at all how that step is possible. I'd be glad if someone could clarify this for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think of  the sum as an [Alternating series](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/error-estimation-for-approximating-alternating-series).

Comment: Hold on... in order to talk about uniform convergence of a function, you need to have a sequence of functions in the first place. Is $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kx^k}{k}$ the sequence?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Yes, that's true. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thank you. This link helped me. Is there any proof of this error estimation?

Comment: It is in the standard Calculus texts. Or, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319390/prove-alternating-series-approximation).